# Doubt on Jpcapcapture

Tags: java, eclipse, importerror, jpcap

I have installed Jpcap0.7. I have copied the jpcap.jar in the necessary folder.

My program needs

```
import jpcap.JpcapHandler;
import jpcap.Jpcap;
import jpcap.Packet;
...
```

It returns an error "the import cannot be resolved". What do i do to resolve this error? I'm using eclipse on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [tell eclipse that this jar file is part of your project](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jar).